# How to make a copy of counter with amsthm package?

Tags: counters, amsthm

So there're 3 classes: ex, exa and exb.
I would like exa and exb inherit the counter/index of ex but they two should be separated.

I've tried this

```
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{exa}[ex]{Exercise A}
\newtheorem{exb}[ex]{Exercise B}
```

And

```
\begin{ex}abc\end{ex}
\begin{ex}abc\end{ex}

\begin{exa}abc\end{exa}
\begin{exa}abc\end{exa}
\begin{exa}abc\end{exa}

\begin{exb}abc\end{exb}
\begin{exb}abc\end{exb}
```

This output looks like

Exercise 1

Exercise 2

Exercise A 3

Exercise A 4

Exercise A 5

Exercise B 6

Exercise B 7

And change it to

```
\newtheorem{exb}{Exercise B} 
\renewcommand{\theexb}{\theex}
```

would give me

Exercise 1

Exercise 2

Exercise A 3

Exercise A 4

Exercise A 5

Exercise B 5

Exercise B 5

but I want

Exercise 1

Exercise 2

Exercise A 3

Exercise A 4

Exercise A 5

Exercise B 3

Exercise B 4